# logback not reloading logback.xml in wildfly10

Tags: wildfly, logback, slf4j, wildfly-10

When I test my application in local (without wildfly) it works. I can go to logback.xml, change some appender and then I can see the changes on lilith.

When I deploy my application on wildfly it doesn't work. This is the logback.xml file:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">

<appender name="lilith-commty" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
    <RemoteHost>192.168.56.1</RemoteHost>
    <Port>4560</Port>
    <ReconnectionDelay>170</ReconnectionDelay>
    <IncludeCallerData>true</IncludeCallerData>
</appender>

<root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="lilith-commty"/>
</root>

<logger name="org.mongodb" additivity="false"> </logger> 
<logger name="io.swagger" additivity="false"> </logger>
<logger name="org.reflections" additivity="false"> </logger>
<logger name="ma.glasnost" additivity="false"> </logger>
```

In server.log from wildfly I've seen these messages:

```
2017-05-08 08:50:58,929 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) 08:50:58,866 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [vfs:/content/commty.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
2017-05-08 08:50:58,931 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) 08:50:58,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [vfs:/content/commty.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
2017-05-08 08:50:58,931 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) 08:50:58,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 10 seconds
```

But then logback shows me that message on the server.log:

```
2017-05-08 08:51:02,021 INFO  [stdout] (logback-5) 08:51:02,021 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1494228032019) - Empty watch file list. Disabling
```

It seems that logback isn't finding the logback.xml so it can't see the changes.

How I can fix that?

Thanks.

EDIT: It seems that the main problem is that logback doesn't know how to solve the url to the logback.xml for reloading it because vfs:

```
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@50d2b290 - URL [vfs:/content/commty.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] is not of type file
```

Any idea?

Comment: How do you deploy your application?

Comment: From eclipse I deploy it on a cent OS with a wildfly10 server application

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse deploys it, but it may not deploy it exploded which would be a problem.

Comment: Well, I deploy it on eclipse with gradle. It seems that is problem of wildfly vfs (virtual file sistem).